# Webpack 2 targeting node doesn't compile JSX

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm building a Universal JS app with React and I'm using webpack 2 to bundle my server side code.

When building the server side code, it seems that webpack isn't transpiling JSX because I'm getting the following error:

[I made a repo to reproduce the error](https://github.com/arhcstolen/webpack-target-node). Clone it, hit ***npm install*** and then ***npm run build:backend*** on the terminal

```
ERROR in ./server/router.js
Module parse failed: webpack-target-node\server\router.js Unexpected token (8:31)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| export default (req, res) => {
|   match({ routes, location: req.url }, (err, redirect, props) => {
|     const app = renderToString(<RouterContext {...props} />);
|
|     const html = `
 @ ./server.js 3:0-46
```

***webpack.config.node.js***

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { resolve } = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = () => {
  return {
    target: 'node',
    entry: './server.js',
    output: {
      path: resolve(__dirname, 'serverBuild'),
      filename: 'server.js'
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [ '', '.js' ]
    },
    externals: [ nodeExternals() ],
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.jsx$/,
          loader: 'babel',
          query: {
            presets: [ 'react', 'stage-0' ]
          },
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          include: resolve('./shared')
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

***server.js***

```
import express from 'express';

import routeMiddleware from './server/router';

const app = express();


app.use('/', express.static(`${__dirname}/build`));

app.use(routeMiddleware);

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Node server is running on http://localhost:3000');
});
```

***server/router.js***

```
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { match, RouterContext } from 'react-router';
import router from '../shared/routes'

export default (req, res) => {
  match({ routes, location: req.url }, (err, redirect, props) => {
    // here is where the building process fails
    const app = renderToString(<RouterContext {...props} />);

    const html = `
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
          <title></title>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="react-app">${app}</div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/bundle.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>`;

    res.send(html);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're telling Webpack to pass `.jsx` files to the Babel loader:

```
test: /\.jsx$/,
loader: 'babel',
```

However, your JSX is contained within `.js` files, like `server/router.js`, so you should expand the test to match both `.js` and `.jsx`:

```
test: /\.jsx?$/
```

Also, you have to remove the `include` property from the Babel loader configuration, because it means that the files that should be processed by the loader *must* exist in the `./shared` directory, and `./server/router.js` doesn't.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it didn't solve the problem, still throws the same error :(

Comment: @AbrahamHurtado I found the issue, see my edit (regarding the `include` property in your Webpack config).

Comment: OMG, that did it! Thank you so much! :)